# How to check for sequential ordering in having clause in HIVE?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I want to be able to write a query that will tell me which groups of my data do not have every number in a sequence.

For example, my table loks like this:

```
Columns:   sequence  group1
           0         ADM
           1         ADM
           0         GDM
           2         GDM
           3         GDM
           0         WJK
```

And, I want to know which unique values in `group1` contain all of the numbers starting at `0` and counting.  So, in this instance, `ADM` and `WJK` would get returned, but `GDM` would not.  `GDM` would not, because it goes from 0, 2, 3 and skips 1.

How would I write a query in `HIVE` to tell me which unique values in column `group1` contain all integers sequentially?

Comment: I removed the superfluous database tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can use count and max, due the fact that sequence start  form zero

```
 select group1
 from my_table 
 group by group1
 having count(*) = max(sequence) +1
```

for your last comment then you can use

```
 select group1
 from my_table 
 group by group1
 having count(distinct sequence) = max(sequence) +1
```

Comment: This will only check if the number of rows is equal to the maximum.  But, there could be 2 rows of the same integer, and 0 rows of the integer that is 1 higher than it.  (e.g. if the `sequence` column for a certain group contained `0, 0, 2,`, then the `count(*)` would still equal the maximum for that group plus 1 (i.e. 3), but it would not be correct).

Comment: @Candic3   i have update the answer .. (if i understand you comment right)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT group1
FROM
    TableName
GROUP BY
    group1
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = MAX(sequence) - MIN(sequence) + 1
```

this works if 0 based or positive integer

Answer (score 0):

If `sequence` can have duplicates, then you need to be careful.  One method is to take a real sequence, subtract it, and be sure the difference is contant:

```
select group1
from (select t.*,
             (sequence - row_number() over (partition by group1 order by sequence)) as diff
      from t
     ) t
group by group1
having min(diff) = max(diff);
```

Comment: `sequence` can have duplicates.  I think a windowing function is the only way to check for this